# BlockUI or bootstrap dialog animation causing visual glitching

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, blockui, inspinia

I have a site running a custom theme built on Bootstrap 3.3.7. After the recent Google Chrome update (this week), any blocking done by the jQuery BlockUI plugin is causing severe visual glitching across the page.

There are also visual issues in dialogs where any animation or selection of text causes black spaces to appear in the dialog.

I've attached some images. The red boxes are to remove any identifying information - everything else is untouched.

[image]
[image: image1]

These issues do not occur in Firefox or Edge, only Chrome. There have been minor issues with dialogs before, with the background being redrawn over dialogs, but they are now much worse.

Not expecting anyone to know exactly what the issue is as am running custom themes and have custom css, but any point in the right direction would be useful - no idea what could be causing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking users to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome fixed this issue completely.